# VSTS CI build errors on CodedUI test for missing references

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests

We are using VSTS to perform Continuous Integration utilizing a build template that was created to deploy a website to a Dev machine.

This worked fine but then we wanted to add in **CodedUI tests** to the build template in order to run the tests as part of the build step.

So I added a **Visual Studio Test** step to the build and added in the test by referencing the test plan and test suite it was associated with.

I made sure the codedUI project was built within the same solution as the website in order to make sure the binaries were built with it.

The problem I'm getting is that when the build runs it brings back errors stating that it is missing the relevant references for the code to work such as:

- QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework
- QualityTools.Common
- TestTools.UITesting

etc.

However these reference are included in the project and "Copy Local" is set to true.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

**UPDATE**
New error received:

> MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class
> 'Email_Regression.CodedUITest1' of assembly
> 'C:\agent_work\4\s\Microservices\Email\Email
> Regression\obj\Release\Email Regression.dll'. Reason Could not load
> file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework,
> Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
>
> No test is available in C:\agent_work\4\s\Microservices\Email\Email
> Regression\bin\Release\Email Regression.dll
> C:\agent_work\4\s\Microservices\Email\Email
> Regression\obj\Release\Email Regression.dll. Make sure that test
> discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version
> settings are appropriate and try again.

Comment: Do you use private build agent? What's the detail error? Is Visual Studio Enterprise or test agent for visual studio installed on that machine? What's the result if you run Coded UI test on that machine manually?

Comment: Yes it's a private build agent. We've just got around the original error by adding the dll's to a folder in the project. However now when the build is run the tests are not found within the Test.dll because it cannot find the CodedUITestFramework assembly or the UITesting assembly.
I'm not sure if Visual studio enterprise is on the agent machine and I haven't got access to attempt running it manually

Comment: Try to add Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task before test task.

Comment: I have that added in already, I haven't tried it without it but I can't imagine that would make a difference

Comment: Try to add Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task to install test agent on target machine and check the result.

Comment: We are using the new tasks in VSTS that apparently don't require that as that task is now listed as deprecated. We kind of use a service agent to handle everything which is why test agents no longer need to be deployed

Comment: The new task is Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task. What's the result after trying with Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task?

Comment: Hi, that wasn't working either but I've talked to Microsoft about it and apparently you need to have Visual Studio Enterprise installed on the machine trying to run the tests. So Continuous Integration, if you want to pay a lot of money for it!

Comment: Just install Test agent for Visual Studio on build agent machine should include the necessary assemblies and can run Coded UI test. On the other hand, you can install Visual Studio Enterprise without buy it.

Answer (score 1):

After talking to the Microsoft help team it appears that you need to have Visual Studio Enterprise edition installed on the machine you wish to run the codedUI tests on.

**Update**

After discussions with Microsoft and highlighting this being a rubbish solution they are now going to deliver the dll's as part of the new vsTestPlatform installer. I'm not saying this is down to my complaints, just coincidental timing.